# Typing text in Combobox placed inside Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, combobox

How to allow Combobox placed inside Datagrid to type text.

It just binding the values already stored in the database. but i need to type the value in the Combobox which is not shown in the bound values.

How to make the Combobox as editable column?

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`ComboBoxStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx) to `DropDown`

> Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and that the text portion is editable. This means that the user can enter a new value and is not limited to selecting an existing value in the list.